# itertools.groupby() not grouping correctly

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have this data:

```
self.data = [(1, 1, 5.0),
             (1, 2, 3.0),
             (1, 3, 4.0),
             (2, 1, 4.0),
             (2, 2, 2.0)]
```

When I run this code:

```
for mid, group in itertools.groupby(self.data, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
```

for `list(group)` I get:

```
[(1, 1, 5.0),
 (1, 2, 3.0),
 (1, 3, 4.0)]
```

which is what I want.

But if I use 1 instead of 0

```
for mid, group in itertools.groupby(self.data, key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
```

to group by the second number in the tuples, I only get:

```
[(1, 1, 5.0)]
```

even though there are other tuples that have "1" in that 1 (2nd) position.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) collects together **contiguous** items with the same key.
If you want all items with the same key, you have to sort `self.data` first.

```
for mid, group in itertools.groupby(
    sorted(self.data,key=operator.itemgetter(1)), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
```

Comment: I had sorted previously on position zero.  So I just sorted again before doing the groupby and it works.  self.data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

Comment: There is no need to sort; you want to use a *dictionary* instead: `grouped = {}` then `for v in self.data: grouped.setdefault(v[1], []).append(v)`. Sorting is an O(NlogN) operation, where using a dictionary to group the values lets you complete the task in O(N) time.

Answer (score 36):

Variant without sorting (via dictionary). Should be better performance-wise.

```
def full_group_by(l, key=lambda x: x):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for item in l:
        d[key(item)].append(item)
    return d.items()
```

Comment: Came back to post the same thing, I hadn't read your answer! This is clearly the way to go :)

Comment: Unfortunately the keys all have to be hashable then, so it doesn't work if those are for examples lists, unlike with `itertools.groupby`...

Comment: @Jeronimo: you'd try to find a hashable reflection of the key; say `tuple()` for a list key or `frozenset(d.items())` for dictionaries, etc. If that's really not possible only then would you have to fall back to the O(NlogN) price of sorting. Using a dictionary to group lets you complete the task in linear (O(N)) time.

Answer (score 1):

Below "fixes" several annoyances with Python's `itertools.groupby`.

```
def groupby2(l, key=lambda x:x, val=lambda x:x, agg=lambda x:x, sort=True):
    if sort:
        l = sorted(l, key=key)
    return ((k, agg((val(x) for x in v))) \
        for k,v in itertools.groupby(l, key=key))
```

Specifically,

1. It doesn't require that you sort your data.
2. It doesn't require that you must use `key` as named parameter only.
3. The output is clean generator of `tuple(key, grouped_values)` where values are specified by 3rd parameter.
4. Ability to apply aggregation functions like sum or avg easily.

**Example Usage**

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
from statistics import *

t = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('a',3)]
for k,v in groupby2(t, itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1), sum):
  print(k, v)
```

This prints,

```
a 4
b 2
```

[Play with this code](https://repl.it/@sytelus/groupby2)

Comment: Why are those 'annoyances'? `groupby()` lets you combine **consecutive matching values* into groups, it was never intended to group across a whole series, which requires reading every value in the input iterable. The core usecase of the `itertools` module is to avoid consuming all values of an iterator, where possible.

Comment: Note that sorting has a cost: it takes O(NlogN) time to sort N items into a sorted sequence. Grouping *using a dictionary* on the other hand takes linear time (O(N)). Your 'utility function' removes the option of avoiding paying the sorting cost., and because you are not using keyword-only arguments, anyone reading your `group2()` calls will have to refer to the documentation each time to figure out what all the arguments do.

Comment: Your `t` would be better processed using `from collections import defaultdict`, `summed = defaultdict(int)`, `for k, v in t: summed[k] += v`, `for k, v in summed: print(k, v)`. That's *much more self-evident* as to what the code achieves, and does so in linear time, no sorting needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The example is just for demo. There are certainly more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: See also: [more_itertools.groupby_transform(iterable, keyfunc=None, valuefunc=None, reducefunc=None)](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.groupby_transform). `keyfunc` is similar to your `key`, `valuefunc` is similar to your `val`, and `reducefunc` is similar to your `agg`.

Comment: I'd argue these "annoyances" are quite legitimate. If you look at comparable utilities in other languages (say .NET LINQ's `GroupBy`), they do not have this requirement. I do not think it is a stretch to suggest that most users of this function are applying it to unordered collections, and thus sorting solely out of necessity. Given the default behavior is now essentially locked in, a keyword argument is a reasonable way to expose this.