# Averaging list of tuples based on key name?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
modifiedL = [('10-1984', 2.8), ('10-1984', 2.8), ('10-1984', 2.85), ('10-1984', 2.82), ('10-1984', 2.78), ('10-1984', 2.75), ('09-1984', 2.82), ('09-1984', 2.9), ('09-1984', 2.9), ('09-1984', 2.94), ('09-1984', 2.99), ('09-1984', 3.02), ('09-1984', 3.05), ('09-1984', 3.04), ('09-1984', 3.11), ('09-1984', 3.22), ('09-1984', 3.13), ('09-1984', 3.09), ('09-1984', 2.94), ('09-1984', 3.02), ('09-1984', 2.97), ('09-1984', 2.98)]

avg={}

for date, value in modifiedL:
    avg.setdefault(date, []).append(value)

for key, value in avg.items():
    avg[key] = sum(value)/float(len(value))
```

After first loop:

```
avg = {'10-1984': [2.8, 2.81, 2.78, 2.77, 2.84, 2.95, 2.92, 2.85, 2.88, 2.88, 2.8, 2.68, 2.7, 2.56, 2.67, 2.68, 2.77, 2.8, 2.8, 2.85, 2.82, 2.78, 2.75], '09-1984': [2.82, 2.9, 2.9, 2.94, 2.99, 3.02, 3.05, 3.04, 3.11, 3.22, 3.13, 3.09, 2.94, 3.02, 2.97, 2.98]}
```

After second loop:

```
avg= {'10-1984': average, '09-1984': average}
```

Is there a way to simplify the code or perform this in one line?

Comment: Are you sure `5559408.695652174` is an average of list with all values in range from 2 to 3?

Comment: its not, its just a snippet from the list because it is quite big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. You can replace some parts of it (like using `defaultdict` or `statistics.mean`), but it will still take 2 loops. There is no practical reason to make every code a one-liner, it is always better to just make a function with a good name.

However, there is some options to make it one-liner. You can use `itertools.groupby` (note that this increases algorithm complexity to O(N log N) :

```
In [11]: from itertools import groupby

In [12]: from operator import itemgetter

In [13]: from statistics import mean

In [14]: {k: mean(map(itemgetter(1), v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(modifiedL, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
Out[14]: {'09-1984': 3.0075, '10-1984': 2.8}
```

You can write your version of groupby which does not require sequence to be sorted to reduce complexity back to O(N) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116666/itertools-groupby-not-grouping-correctly) for examples)

Or if you're using pandas in your project you can just convert the list to a DataFrame:

```
In [29]: import pandas as pd

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(modifiedL)

In [31]: df.groupby(0).mean()
Out[31]:
              1
0
09-1984  3.0075
10-1984  2.8000
```