# Group emails into TO & CC with itertools.groupby and convert it to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, itertools-groupby

I'd like to group emails by their domain and convert the result into a dictionary. So far I have figured out that `itertools.groupby` with a custom *func* will do that. It correctly assigns keys to each value, but when I try to create a dictionary only the last value is used when the values to be grouped are not continues.

```py
import re
from itertools import groupby

{k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(["bar", "foo", "baz"], key=lambda x: "to" if re.search(r"^b", x) else "cc")}
```

This will produce `{'to': ['baz'], 'cc': ['foo']}` instead of `{'to': ['bar', 'baz'], 'cc': ['foo']}`.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) OR [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and `extend` in `list` like below.

```
# from collections import defaultdict
# dct = defaultdict(list)

from itertools import groupby
import re

dct = {}
for k, v in groupby(["awol", "bar", "foo", "baz"], 
                    key=lambda x: "to" if re.search(r"^b", x) else "cc"):
    dct.setdefault(k,[]).extend(list(v))

    # If you use 'dct = defaultdict(list)'. You can add item in 'list' like below
    # dct[k].extend(list(v))
print(dct)
```

---

```
{'cc': ['awol', 'foo'], 'to': ['bar', 'baz']}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t Python added `groupby` in 2003. What was the situation like back then? How many other programming languages even had such grouping functionality back then?

Comment: @AndrejKesely there ware databases that already have established what to expect from a `groupby`. They should have named this one `group_consecutive` or make it at least an option so that one doesn't have to wonder WTF. I googled and I see that already 10 years ago people were wondering about its mechanics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116666/itertools-groupby-not-grouping-correctly

Answer (score 3):

Sort the group first to get correct result (`itertools.groupby` groups *continuous* items):

```py
import re
from itertools import groupby

out = {
    k: list(v)
    for k, v in groupby(
        sorted(
            ["awol", "bar", "foo", "baz"],
            key=lambda x: bool(re.search(r"^b", x)),
        ),
        key=lambda x: "to" if re.search(r"^b", x) else "cc",
    )
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'cc': ['awol', 'foo'], 'to': ['bar', 'baz']}
```

Comment: ["awol" went awol](https://tio.run/##PU7LCoMwELznK5Y9JSC99FKEfklpIWqsweiGTbTa0m@3UdvOZRjmwfg5NtQfT56XxXaeOAIbUTN1YKPhSOQCfI070@CLWQgaIpzhJSChzcHZEOWoNlkTQ5vBCLb/5eVmrAhpxVTygvpBDjPAQvNKNdGunnhV2T/emvnsdFdUGqYcMBKCrdO9QzCay0Yy3orUmxQYFwxgWeJeVuIthGfbR5muqmX5AA)...

Comment: @KellyBundy Good catch, the `key=` parameter in sort needs to be similar than the function in `.groupby` (edited).

Comment: (And that's why the doc says *"it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function"*)